# saving an image with a transparent background

Tags: python, image, pygame, png, alpha

i've got some issues with my program:

```
minimap = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
background = pygame.Surface((minimap.get_width(), minimap.get_height()))
background.fill((0, 0, 0))
background.set_alpha(0)
minimap.blit(background, (0, 0, minimap.get_width(), minimap.get_height()))
pygame.image.save(minimap, "minimap.png")
```

the thing is, I want the background to be transparent because I display it on something else later on and i want to see behind it, so I've used another surface where I've set a color and put the alpha to 0, after that the background is set to minimap.

If you have any clue please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background` doesn't have a per pixel alpha format. Set the [`SRCALPHA`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) flag to create a surface with an image format that includes a per-pixel alpha. Don't fill the background with an opaque black color:

<s>`background = pygame.Surface((minimap.get_width(), minimap.get_height()))`</s>
<s>`background.fill((0, 0, 0))`</s>
<s>`background.set_alpha(0)`</s>

```py
background = pygame.Surface(minimap.get_size(), pygame.SRCALPHA)
```

Alternatively you can set a transparent color key with [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)

```py
background = pygame.Surface((minimap.get_width(), minimap.get_height()))
background.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer all my problems ^^